# How to disable user login from multiple locations at the same time?

Tags: authentication

I want to control account sharing. The user account can be only logged into my web application once at a time. I thought of checking IP or browser type but seems not good enough.

What's the best solution?

Comment: So you're going to force me to run a proxy server in order to have a login on my laptop and my desktop at the same time?  Why?

Comment: That is a problem.. Maybe I should implement a notification method to ask the previous logged-in user to permit the second login?

Answer (score 0):

The combination of IP address and User agent string should be good enough to unique a user.  User agent strings are highly variable.  Edit:  this assumes you want to allow a single user to be able to view the app in multiple browser tabs / windows from a single location.  Is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

IP address alone is not sufficient :

- Several users can have the same IP address (users behind a proxy at work, for instance)
- A single user can have several IP addresses (that was the case a couple of years ago for AOL users, for instance)

In that kind of situation, I generally use something based on a combinaison of :

- IP address
- And several other HTTP headers, like, for instance :

  - User-Agent *(for instance, it can be as complex as "`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1.7pre) Gecko/20091221 Ubuntu/9.10 (karmic) Firefox/3.5.6`")*
  - Accept *(for instance, "`text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`")*
  - Accept-Language *(for instance, "`fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3`")*
  - Accept-Charset *(for instance, "`ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7`")*

If only on of those is different from the previous request, I consider it's OK ; but if more than 2 or 3 of those are different, it's strange, and it often mean it's not the same user.